# How could I extend static ips in cluster at gcp organization to unlimited instead of 8 IPs now?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a cluster on GCP organization, the cluster has 8 static IPs, and I need many static IPs for my projects in that cluster.

How could I do that?

I tried to search and I hope to solve my problem.

Comment: Hi there. Is not quite clear for me if you mean tha you have a  /28 for the nodes in the VPC so you are constrained only to 8 nodes, or if you tried to add more nodes and you got a quota problem. What error you got or what you tried to achieve that you only have 8 ips and where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a Quota issue. From the console navigate to IAM & Admin > Quotas and search for "Static IP". Select the region you want more IP's in and click on edit Quotas and put in a request for an IP Increase request

Keep in mind that Static public IP's cost money

Comment: thanks for your support, I appreciate that. If I requested 200 IP in my quota, I would pay for my only use, not for all unused, that right?

Comment: Correct you only pay for the ones IN_USE.